# how to make a ts function autocomplete with enum values

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

what i'm trying to do is similar to this

```
enum Color 
{
  RED="RED",
  GREEN="GREEN",
  BLUE="BLUE"
}

function setColor(color:Color)
{

}
```

and when i want to call the function

```
setColor("RED"),
```

i get the error :

```
Argument of type '"RED"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Color'.ts(2345),
```

i know i can use

`setColor("Red" as Color)`,

but i want the RED to be autocompleted when i type,
how can i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call your function `setColor()` with a string literal argument (e. g. (`setColor("RED")`) you should use a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) instead of an [`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

```
type Color = "RED" | "Green" | "Blue";
declare function setColor(color: Color): unknown;
setColor("RED");
```

You can achieve this dynamically with your enum by using `keyof typeof Color`.

```
enum Color {
  RED = "RED",
  GREEN = "GREEN",
  BLUE = "BLUE"
}
declare function setColor(color: keyof typeof Color): unknown;
setColor("RED");
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJygXigIgEoFEAimUAPlgOLIQQB2RpmAQggK4SYDcAUACYQDGCAIaUoAM2bU%20wAJZxqUAM4Rg8JMgAUfRCgBcsbcgCUeiQGtqcAO7UuSlQfU4CmQ1041mAW31qATFABvTigoPHx0LDDMABpgqDI8XAA5CMwE3GSYuIYAGQBVXFTcgsxOAF8efiERcUkZOUVlVRRfTQM9UwgQOFEoUEgenxbjKDMLa1smg1anQldOTiA)